# Using javascript function parameters to show jquery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, tabs

Actually I am trying to do jquery tabs. I have written a code that needs rework and probably better ways to implement. I think I could use function arguments to achieve this, but I am not sure. Can somebody tell me how to achieve this in a better way. Though my code works but I think it is rudimentary. I would also like only one tab to display a background color if this is active.

http://jsfiddle.net/5nB4P/

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">First Tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second Tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Third Tab</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
<div class="tabs first">First Div content</div>
<div class="tabs">Second Div content</div>
<div class="tabs">Third Div content</div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(function() {
    $("li :eq(0)").click(function() {
            $("li").css("background","none");
            $(this).css("background","red");
            $(".tabs:gt(0)").hide();
            $(".tabs:eq(0)").show();
    })
    $("li :eq(1)").click(function() {
    $("li").css("background","none");
            $(this).css("background","red");
    $(this).css("background","red")
            $(".tabs:gt(1), .tabs:lt(1)").hide();
            $(".tabs:eq(1)").show();
    })
    $("li :eq(2)").click(function() {
    $("li").css("background","none");
            $(this).css("background","red");
            $(".tabs:lt(2)").hide();
            $(".tabs:eq(2)").show();
    })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a much better way to achieve this. Here you go

```
$(function() {
    $("li").click(function() {
       $(this).css("background","red").siblings().css("background","none");
       $(".tabs").hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
       return false;
    });
})
```

Working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5nB4P/8/)**

As @Niels mentioned for setting the background style you can have a dedicated class(active) and add/remove this class instead of setting the inline sytle.

FYI..In the above code `$(this).index()` gives the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements

Comment: Actually I want the red border to kind of distinguish between the two unselected tabs. Actually the 1px solid red border should be around the selected tab and its below div

Comment: Is return false mandatory and can we get rid of border bottom of 1px solid red for selected tab

Comment: Returning false will prevent default behavior of anchor because which browser will scroll to the top when u click. You can remove the border of the selected tab by applying styles to anchor border to white color

Comment: Thanks and how are you setting the first tab by default to red background, Neil is doing .eq(0).addClass("active");

Comment: In the demo yes I am calling the click event handler on the first li element.

Comment: I mean how is it is default set to red background. I mean once you load the page you see the first tab with background red. how is that happening

Comment: Take  a look at this  http://jsfiddle.net/5nB4P/14/. In this I am calling the `click` event handler on the first `li` element using `eq(0).click()` which will set the background to the element being clicked.

Comment: Thanks but i still didnt understand how you set the background red on page load to the first tab in your first fiddle without eq(0).click()

Answer (score 3):

CSS:

```
.active {
    background-color:red;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $('.tabs:eq(' + $this.index() + ')').show().siblings().hide();
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5nB4P/6/

Comment: I want the 1px border to be around the tab and its selected div only

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/tsukasa1989/5nB4P/1/

```
$(function() {
    $("#nav li").click(function(){
         // Handle active status
         $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");

        // Show the tab at the index of the LI
        $(".tabs").hide().eq($(this).index()).show();        
    })
    // Don't forget to set first tab as active one at start
    .eq(0).addClass("active");
})
```

If you want to style the active tab use

```
#nav li.active{}
```

Comment: Can 1px solid border be around the div and its highlighted tab only

Comment: You can change the .active class to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks Niels, do you have any Idea how can the first tab be set default background of red without using .eq(0).addClass("active");

Comment: hi Niels I was using bind to have the tab background red on hover, I used mouseenter and mouseleave, but mouseleave also removes the background red from clicked tab. how do i fix that, do u know? and thanks for reading through

Comment: You need to save the active tab, because now I think you are moving the active tab to the current hovered element, and when you mouseleave none is selected. Are you still using the click to select a tab?

Comment: yes click will select the tab, basically all is same, I am just trying to use background -red on hover of mouse

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way that I updated this to make it smaller and I believe to be more effective and easier to use:

http://jsfiddle.net/5nB4P/7/

Code:

```
$("#nav ul li").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("rel");
    $("#nav ul li").each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("#content div").each(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $("#"+id).show();
});
```

Comment: You don't have to loop through the DIV's to hide them, you can just do `$("#content div").hide()` since jQuery is array build and will loop it for you.

Answer (score 0):

My approach doesn't use arguments, but HTML `class` and `id` references to shorten things: http://jsfiddle.net/ZScGF/1/

Comment: Did you paste the wrong fiddle link, You have exactly my code there

Comment: Oops, my bad... I've updated my answer with the correct link.

Comment: Cab border 1px be around only the div and its tab, e-g when selecting the first tab only this tab should have border on top left and right sides, the edge between div and tab1 should not be having any borders